# Prove that $f(A \cap f^{-1}(B))=f(A) \cap B$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm attempting to prove that for a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $A \subset X$, $B \subset Y$, the following equality holds: $$ f \left( A \cap f^{-1}(B) \right) = f(A) \cap B. $$

"$\mathbf{\subset}$": Using that $f(A \cap A') \subset f(A) \cap f(A')$ and $f(f^{-1}(B)) \subset B$, we get $$ f \left( A \cap f^{-1}(B) \right) \subset f(A) \cap f\left(f^{-1}(B)\right) \subset f(A) \cap B. $$

"$\mathbf{\supset}$": For the reverse direction, I derived the following proof:

$$ \begin{align*}
y \in f(A) \cap B &\Longleftrightarrow y \in f(A) \wedge y \in B \\
&\Longleftrightarrow (\exists x \in A : f(x) = y) \wedge y \in B \\
&\Longleftrightarrow \exists x \in A : f(x) = y \wedge x \in f^{-1}(B) \\ &\Longleftrightarrow \exists x \in A \cap f^{-1}(B) : f(x) = y \\
&\Longleftrightarrow y \in f \left( A \cap f^{-1}(B) \right)
\end{align*} $$

While I'm aware from other questions that the overall direction is correct, there seems to be a flaw in how I've articulated the proof since it demonstrates equality, which I suspect might not be accurate.

I also apologize for the formatting issues but I couldn't manage the equation to be displayed as multi-line equation.

**Update**
I'm not a big fan of simply chaining equations without much explanation. However on of my professors uses this extensively in his course. Therefore I though this would be a good exercise. Furthermore I'm interested in whether the equivalency is true or not. I suspect it's not but am not sure where my error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y\in f(A)\cap B.$ Then $y=f(\color{red}x)$, with $\color{red}x\in \color{red}A$ and $y\in B$. Then $\color{red}x\in \color{red}{f^{-1}(B)}.$ And finally $y\in f(A\cap f^{-1}(B))$ . So, $$f(A)\cap B\subset f(A\cap f^{-1}(B))$$

Let $y\in f(A\cap f^{-1}(B))$. $\exists x\in A\cap f^{-1}(B), \color{red}{y=f(x)}$. $x\in A$. So, $\color{red}y\in f(A). x\in f^{-1}(B)$. So, $\color{red}{f(x)}\in B $ and $\color{red}y\in B$. So, $y\in f(A)\cap B$. So,  $$f(A\cap f^{-1}(B))\subset f(A)\cap B$$
So $$\boxed{f(A\cap f^{-1}(B))= f(A)\cap B}\color{green}{(*)}$$

---

**Update**: no problem in your equivalences : $$ \begin{align*}
y \in f(A) \cap B &\Longleftrightarrow y \in f(A) \wedge y \in B \\
&\Longleftrightarrow (\exists x \in A : f(x) = y) \wedge y \in B \\
&\Longleftrightarrow \exists x \in A : f(x) = y \wedge x \in f^{-1}(B) \\ &\Longleftrightarrow \exists x \in A \cap f^{-1}(B) : f(x) = y \\
&\Longleftrightarrow y \in f \left( A \cap f^{-1}(B) \right)
\end{align*} $$

But then, it is clumsy to claim to have worked by double inclusion: these equivalences are sufficient to prove $\color{green}{(*)}$.

Comment: Can you point out where my proof fails?

Comment: For reverse inclusion, there is no need for equivalence; all it takes is implications that are simpler to handle. That's what I wanted to point out.

Comment: I think "⊂" is treated well and I wanted to come up with an alternative method.

Comment: I know that it's not needed. However, if the equivalency is true, I wouldn't need to show "$\subset$" and "$\supset$".